# Printing posted values from Paypal in notify url using php

Tags: php, paypal, notify

I have integrated the paypal standard payment method using php. I would like to see or print the posted values from Paypal in notify url

```
<input  name="notify_url"     type="hidden"   value="<?=get_permalink( 1051 );?>" >
```

I am sending the return url as well. So after payment Paypal is redirecting me to the return url specified but how can I hit the notify url at the same time and print or echo the posted values.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: insert javascript code to call the notify url in "return url" page.

Comment: @JPKim Any example of js/jquery code please.

Comment: I dunno much about the PayPal integration, but if your return url have or can see the posted value, then u can ajax call notify_url with the posted value (I can show you examples of the code if thats what you want), but if you don't have or can't see the value then you have to implement IPN instead of PDT according to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415964/paypal-notify-url-and-return-url-receiving-variables-without-ipn-using-php

Comment: @JPKim IPN/PDT is activated. I just need to get the posted values from notify url to return url.

Comment: so the issue is you can't get posted value because notify url is not called, right?  According to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ , you should have notified if you implemented IPN listener correctly. In order to get more answers from community, you would have to post more codes (i.e. notify_url, payment page, etc. )to identify what's wrong.

Comment: @JPKim Finally the ipn is working. The notify url was missing.