# Retrieve donor information after he/she donated

Tags: paypal

After somebody clicks the donate button in my website, is there any way my site can retrieve information like:

1. the donation was successful
2. donation amount
3. time the donation was completed

and then, the information will be stored automatically in one of my site databases

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `notify_url` variable to your Donate button (or link) with URL of script on your site. That script receives POST with all payment data.

Example:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations"/>
....
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.example.com/paypal.php"/>
....
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9"/>
<input type="image" src="..." border="0" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The POST includes among other these fields that would interest you:

```
payment_status = Completed  
payment_gross = 9.00  
payment_fee = 0.65  
residence_country = NL  
payer_email = donor@example.com  
first_name = Jon  
last_name = de Miranda
```

See also question [Notify url of Paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2865970/850848).